# Interpretar se link esta sendo executado pelo navegador ou pelo cronjob

Tags: php, cron, task

Estou com um cronjob funcionando mas praticamente o *link*(código em PHP) esta publico pois para o cronjob funcionar o sistema de verificação de autenticação fica desabilitado. Então gostaria de saber alguma forma para que este *link* não fique publico pelo navegador, e somente o cronjob faça ele funcionar sem autenticação.

Comment: Poderia acrescentar como está o cronjob? Você por acaso está usando curl? Se não, basta remover o arquivo da pasta "public_html", por exemplo, e mover para a pasta anterior, isso será suficiente para ocultar o arquivo do público e ainda ser capaz de chamar o arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

Em vez de usar o motor do servidor de páginas, use o modo CLI do interpretador.
Por exemplo no php você pode digitar na linha de comando "php-cli /hosts/dominioexemplo.com.br/www/nomepagina.php" e ele retornará a saída no bash.
Só usar essa linha no cron. 
Pesquise as opções do CLI como verbosidade e timeout para melhorar a performance, e como utilizar os retornos. ;)
PHP, Perl, Python -> Todos funcionam na linha de comando.

Ach oque é isso que você necessita: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/run-php-scripts-from-cron-jobs

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!

Comment: Na verdade pela linha de comando e mesmo a melhor opção, mas como minha hospedagem é windows entrei em contato com o suporte da hospedagem e alegaram que somente pode ser acessado a linha de comando pelo 'putty', mas tenho tido problemas para configurar ele e sem sucesso ate agora minha unica opção foi recorrer ao cronjob do painel de controle da hospedagem desta forma mesmo. Voce sabe de alguma maneira pra eu ter acesso à linha de comando?

Comment: Olá Luciano,
Depende do serviço de hospedagem, e dos próprios recursos do painel, isso pode ocorrer.
Qual o gerenciador de hospedagem que disponibilizam?

OUTRA OPÇÃO: Utilize uma chave encriptada para adicionar ao querystring do CRON, assim você valida na página, e mesmo ela pública, não teria problema. Para reforçar, utilize restrições de diretório na hospedagem para somente o ip do servidor acessar. ;)
Me avise. 
Abraço!